# How to generate possible binary combinations of 3 bits binary?

Tags: sql, function, binary

I have written below function. Please refer comments in function for more details.

```
 DROP FUNCTION dbo.[combination]
 GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[combination] (
    @Fruits VARCHAR(200),  --comma separated value
    @Vegetables VARCHAR(200),
    @Junkfood NVARCHAR(max)
) RETURNS @FinalTable table (
    result int

)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @countisFruit int    DECLARE @countisVegetable int     DECLARE @countisJunkfood int DECLARE @test int
    DECLARE @isFruitAvailable int DECLARE @isVegetableAvailable int DECLARE @isJunkFoodAvailable int
    SELECT @isFruitAvailable = LEN(REPLACE(@Fruits, CHAR(44), ''))
    SELECT @isVegetableAvailable = LEN(REPLACE(@Vegetables, CHAR(44), ''))
    SELECT @isJunkFoodAvailable = LEN(REPLACE(@Junkfood, CHAR(44), ''))


    BEGIN

    IF @countisFruit > 0
        BEGIN 
        SELECT @isFruitAvailable = 1
        END
    IF @countisVegetable > 0
        BEGIN 
        SELECT @isVegetableAvailable = 1
        END
    IF @countisJunkfood > 0
        BEGIN 
        SELECT @isJunkFoodAvailable = 1
        END


    --<.......Here I want to have if conditions based on what kinds of food is available 
    -- i can achieve it  by having if conditions like 
    --if (@countisFruit > 0 AND @countisVegetable >0 AND @countisJunkfood> 0 )
    --if (@countisFruit = 0 AND @countisVegetable >0 AND @countisJunkfood> 0 ) and so on possible conditions 
    -- I am thinking reading from @count<X> in every if statement might slow down my function 
    --- so I can represent possible combinations in binary  like 000, 101, 111 ... for that I will have to do some logic on @countisFruit and rest @count<X> variables.
    -- Please suggest how can i achieve that

RETURN
END
GO
```

Please suggest how can i achieve these combinations or something of this sort in sql function.  I am trying to optimize lots of ifs involved in this function.

Comment: It is hard to guess what the actual purpose of this code is. Please provide sample data, expected results, and an explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: :(... Tried editing it with some more information

Comment: @vidyashi . . . As a hint:  sample data and desired results are really helpful.  If you really need a function, examples of inputs and outputs, as well as a clear explanation help.

Comment: What Database is this?

Comment: it is sql database

Answer (score 1):

Note the explanation and the parameters are not having any relationship.
If you want to find the number of elements in a comma separated list:
Assuming that this is for SQL Server, here is a way to find the count.

```
declare @input1 varchar(555) ='23,ABC,67, PQR5,267,XYZ236,Emp1, Emp2', @countInput1 int

SELECT @countInput1 = SUM(LEN(@input1) - LEN(replace(@input1, ',', '')) +1)  
SELECT @countInput1 as countInput1
```

So you can do the same for the other 2 as well, you can find the values for your insert.